# Iteration issues using Linear Search

Tags: c#, loops, terminal, format

In my code I have to run through some files with a load of numbers in and at some point need the user to input a number to see if it is in the file or not , if it is in the file then the returning output should be the positioning of where in the file. If it is not in the list then I need to return the closest value to their input. Eg 669 is in the list however 668 is not. My code is as follows for a function to find the nearest value:

```
static int nearest(int close_num, int[] a)
{
int result = -1;
long smallestDelta = long.MaxValue;

foreach (int bob in a)
{
    long delta = (bob > close_num) ? (bob - close_num) : (close_num - bob);

    if (delta < smallestDelta)
    {
        smallestDelta = delta;
        result = bob;
    }
}

return result;
```

Then the linear search and the rest is as follows :

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to find out if is in the selected Net File:  ");
        int i3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)//looping through array
        {
            if (a[i] == i3)//checking to see the value is found in the array
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Value found and the position of it in the selected Net File is: " + i, a[i]);
                break;

            }
            else

            {

                int found = nearest(i3, a);
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot find this number in the Net File however here the closest number to that: " + found);
```

However these are my outputs:[Output 1 : Entering a value that is the file , for some reason prints the else call 3x before , if I remove the break in the code it just breaks. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QebDy.png)

[Output 2: Prints whilst running through the whole list of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCKVR.png)

how can I fix these formatting issues bc the code is doing what I need it to , just not in a way it should.
Thanks

Comment: You should not output(Console.WriteLine("Cannot..Find....)  in the else block. you can write "couldn't find"out of for loop because there you know it's not found in the array and then you can find nearest.

Comment: @MD error if I do that , 2does not exist in current context"

Comment: I assumed you know how loops and conditions work, plus your syntax is not correct.